# How to delete indirectly self-dependent package

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I want to remove the package for the `/usr/bin/jupyter` binary.
Consequently:

```
$ pacman -Qo /usr/bin/jupyter
/usr/bin/jupyter is owned by python-jupyter_core 4.11.0-1
$ pacman -R python-jupyter_core
checking dependencies...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing python-jupyter_core breaks dependency 'python-jupyter_core' required by jupyter-nbformat
:: removing python-jupyter_core breaks dependency 'python-jupyter_core' required by python-jupyter_client
```

This tells me, that this package was installed by another package. I then used pactree to figure out which:

```
$ pactree -r python-jupyter_core
python-jupyter_core
├─jupyter-nbformat
│ └─jupyter-nbclient
└─python-jupyter_client
  ├─jupyter-nbclient
  └─python-ipykernel
    └─python-jupyter_client
```

However, when I try to remove the start of the tree `python-jupyter_client` I again get a dependency warning:

```
$ pacman -R python-jupyter_client
checking dependencies...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing python-jupyter_client breaks dependency 'python-jupyter_client' required by jupyter-nbclient
:: removing python-jupyter_client breaks dependency 'python-jupyter_client' required by python-ipykernel
```

**How can I remove the package(s) that led to the installation of `/usr/bin/jupyter`?**

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I installed `jupyter` using `pip` with `sudo` (not a smart idea). Consequently:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall jupyter-core
```

Is the answer.

Comment: So the title of the question doesn't seem right, right?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It was the question I had. The answer does not fit the title rather. If I would have had searched for my question and this answer would have already existed for that question I would not have needed to ask the question. However, with a different title I might not have found it. I would argue against changing the title.